# Get enum values(from .dll) to list

Tags: c#, .net

I have created some `enums` as `.dll` dynamically using data from database.

I am looking a way to get the values of `enum` to a `list`.

I can access each value separately when I add the reference from each `.dll` to project

```
eg. MyEnum.value1
```

I tried using [Type.GetMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/424c79hc.aspx) to get values, but no luck.

Is there any way I can get all the values in `enum` to a list?

**Update**

I also try Enum.GetValues() but it comes up with an error

***'EnumeratedTypes.MyEnum' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'***

Thanks

Comment: Does [Enum.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) suits you needs?

Comment: Did you tried Enum.GetValues(yourType) ? Or, if you prefer the names : Enum.GetNames(yourType)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What does "created some enums as .dll" mean?  Does Enum.GetValues do what you want?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: I created enum dynamically using **EnumBuilder** to dll files. So now I want get the values inside dll to list

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumeratedTypes.MyEnum));

Comment: @DmitryG sounds like you're using the wrong syntax a bit. Are you using exactly: `System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))`?  EDIT: ahh yeah, guess so.

Comment: Your question does not make a great deal of sense.  Your enumeration by default is like set to an `int` value.  What exactly do you want to achieve by making a `List` of enumeration values?  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumeratedTypes.MyEnum))`

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Tree
{
    Trunk
};

Tree.Trunk.EnumToList();
```

Using this extension:

```
public static List<T> EnumToList<T>(this T source)
{
    Type enumType = typeof(T);

    // Can't use type constraints on value types, so have to do check like this
    if (enumType.BaseType != typeof(Enum))
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be of type System.Enum");

    return new List<T>(Enum.GetValues(enumType) as IEnumerable<T>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast to an int and sum such as:

```
public enum myNums
{
    Alpha = 1,
    Beta = 10,
    Gamma = 100
}

void Main()
{

    var value  = System.Enum.GetValues( typeof( myNums ) )
                           .OfType<myNums>()
                           .Sum (n => (int)n);

    Console.WriteLine ( value ); // 111

}

// Define other methods and classes here
```